# Websites Listing Maven Transitive Dependencies

Tags: maven

Within my organisation, I'm heavily regulated by an IT security body. As such, all access to maven mirrors is prohibited. However, I can provide details of the dependencies I require so that the IT security bods can perform their checks / scans, and hopefully download the binaries for me.

I then install these in my local maven repo, which means that they're freely available to my team inside the firewall.

The beauty of maven is that it can identify and download transitive dependencies. However, without being able to access external POM files, I cannot perform these checks via maven dependency:tree.

As a result, I have to provide the dependencies one-at-a-time to the IT department. Given the depth of some of the dependency chains, this can take quite some time to go back/forward with IT. Alternatively, I do the dependency:tree at home, and mail myself the results.

I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions of websites where I can query for this information? So if I want (say) log4j:1.2.17, it will tell me that I also need to ask for javax.mail:mail:1.4.3 too.

Comment: It is not perfect but mvnrepository.com gives you one level of dependency with their version. ex: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j/1.2.17

Comment: @Olivier.Roger you'd be suprised how quickly this gets tedious! A lot of libraries have much deeper dependency chains than you would expect. I was even considering writing a shell script to wget the page, scrape the HTML and repeat.... but decided that was a step too far!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately I'm not aware of any sites that give you the full transitive dependency information, but there is a good solution *to the underlying problem*.

Namely, you can try to convince management **to use a repository manager with an artifact auditing feature**.

*Sonatype Nexus* [certainly has this](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/why) (see "Artifact Procurement"), *JFrog Artifactory* [seems to enable this as well](http://www.jfrog.com/home/v_artifactorypro_features) (through License Control"), both as extras in paid editions.

Such an approach will **save time and money in the long run**. Repository managers are much *less fragile* than a shared local repo:

- they are an explicit entity intended for this purpose (and Maven has specific settings explicitly intended for working with them),
- they have dedicated authentication/authorization mechanisms that can be made to work with existing ones in your company,
- you can use the deploy plugin with them to properly publish build artifacts,
- etc. etc.

Another relevant reason that may sway over your security body is that you're be able to use the same auditing procedure both for external *and* internal artifacts.

Comment: This is interesting, it would involve teaching the IT department more about java and how dependencies work (which could be interesting, as we don't speak the same language - literally).

I think this is a reasonable approach, and if nobody else can come up with a service that offers this, it seems like the right answer.

Comment: @jwa : I'm glad to hear this possibility exists in your case, and you have my sympathies regarding the current setup. Switching to a repository manager has more advantages, of course, which you can use as additional "argument ammo".